# How to fix Object has unapplied transformations. This will never work for a mesh with an armature. Export cancelled

Tags: export, blender, babylonjs

I have been creating a game these past few weeks. I've been following tutorials to make a blender character. But when I try to export it using the latest babylon.js exporter, it give me this error. `Mesh: Character has unapplied transformations.  This will never work for a mesh with an armature.  Export cancelled` This is my blender file: https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=77613_Simple_Character__rigged_(1).zip. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usually only applies to scale, having an object scale that is not 1.0 often causes issues.

With the object selected, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*->Scale* to [apply the scale](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply) to the object so that it's scale gets set to 1.0, then export.

If you still get the error try also applying the rotation. If you still have trouble, maybe try the [three.js exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/utils/exporters/blender).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. It turns out that I changed the transformations but didn't apply them :/ .  After that I was able to successfully able to export my Character.blend file to babylon.js. Once again, thanks.